# How can I create a value_type type trait?

Tags: c++, string, traits, value-type

I am writing a program that will deal heavily with strings of varying types (i.e. `std::string`, `std::string_view`, `const char*`, `char[]`, and friends with varying `CharT`). So, I am interesting in writing a trait that can abstract getting the value type of generic array-like structures. For the previously listed types, the correct return type would be `char`.

However, I can not seem to get the implementation correct to allow for generic types. Consider the following attempt:

```cpp
template<class T>
struct value_type{
    using type = std::conditional_t<
            std::is_class_v<T>,
            typename T::value_type,
            std::conditional_t<
                std::is_pointer_v<T>,
                std::remove_pointer_t<T>,
                // etc.
    >;
};
```

This, of course, does not compile because not all types have a nested `value_type` typedef.

Is there any way to implement this trait effectively?

Comment: How about `typename std::iterator_traits<decltype(std::begin(std::declval<T>()))>::value_type;`? It won't work for `const char*`, but you can't iterate over that anyways (without wrapping it in a `std::string_view` anyways)

Answer (score 1):

You might use specialization (and SFINAE):

```
template<class T, Enabler = void>
struct value_type;

template<class T>
struct value_type<T, std::void_t<typename T::value_type>>
{
    using type = typename T::value_type;
};

template<class T>
struct value_type<const T*>
{
    using type = T;
};

template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct value_type<const T[N]>
{
    using type = T;
};

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can defer to a helper class template. Fortunately type aliases aren't instantiated during an implicit instantiation:

```
template <class T>
struct get_value_type {
  using type = typename T::value_type;
};

template <class T>
struct value_type {
  using type = typename std::conditional_t<
      std::is_class_v<T>,
      get_value_type<T>,
      std::conditional<std::is_pointer_v<T>, std::remove_pointer_t<T>, void> 
  >::type;
};
```

This will also require you to change the second `std::conditional_t` to `std::conditional` so that we can get `::type` from whatever type is returned.